# SSH no longer works after adding second NIC Card with different subnet

Tags: centos, ssh

I have a CentOS 7 VM on ESXI. The IP is 192.168.22.31. I set up SSH keys and I can get to it just fine from my machine (192.168.21.9) with the private key as well as ssh to it using the password.
However, after adding a second NIC Card in the 192.168.21.x subnet I am no longer able to SSH to it either using the private key or with a password. The error messages are:

```
ssh: connection to host <CentOS VM> port 22: Connection timed out
```

when attempting to use the private key/config file

and

```
kex_exchange_identifaction: read: Connection reset
```

when attempting to ssh with username/password.

Any pointers at where I should look to start trouble shooting this are greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @QuartzCristal definitely not the real IPs. I spaced out while writing and forgot 192 needs the next octet to be 168 in order for it to be non-routable.

Comment: Are you able to ping `192.168.22.31` ? Do you know how to use `nmap` ? Is it detecting port 22 open on that computer (if ping works, that is)?

Comment: Could you post your (of your computer) route table? Is there any router between your computer and the server, or are both on the same network?

Comment: Looks like routing problem, does arp command(or arp -an), in target VM show any host in 192.168.21.X range ? Did you check VLAN in ESX configuration?

Comment: Added the output of routel. I did not check the VLAN in the ESX. Was thinking that since I can ssh to it fine when the second NIC card is not installed it would have to do with the SSH configuration. I'm not too knowledgeable about that though and googling the past few days I haven't found anything that points to the cause.

Comment: You can get from your client 192.168.21.9 to the server 192.168.22.31. Therefore either you're running a larger subnet than night be expected for 192.168.x.y addresses (/24) or there's a router. If there's a router you can't just create 192.168.21.x and expect it to work: it won't. If instead you're using a larger subnet than /24 make sure all your devices are using it

Comment: I've just seen you've a picture. What does it say? Please don't post pictures of text

Comment: (1) The default route for the `22` network is **static** (where is that being configured?).  (2) The default route (where all packets will go if no more detailed route is found, i.e. the internet) is different on each NIC, why? Are there **two** routers with those addresses?. (3) Why is ens192 not using dhcp from the router it is connected to ?

Comment: What is the bridge configuration for the VM ?

Comment: I believe that the issue is becoming quite complex and that you need help from the network manager or some network expert on your company. Good luck.

Comment: Two default routes? Well that won't work: by definition there must be no more than one active default route

Comment: Thank you @roaima. Finally got it. Installed net-tools on the server and deleted all of the entries in the routing table that had any 192.168.21.X entry and now it is working. Thank you everyone who took time to comment. You're all AWESOME!